# How to linkTo properly to a item of a list in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have resources and routes in Ember.js like this:

```
  this.resource('ranking', function() {
    this.route('best', { path: '/best' });
    this.route('new', { path: '/new' });
  });
  this.resource('profile', {path: '/profile/:id' });
```

And data route like this:

```
App.RankingBestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function()
  {
      return App.Profile.find();
  }
});
```

When i go to ../profile/1 it displays the proper profile, and when i go to ../profile/2 also.

My template of Best Ranking looks like this:

```
{{#each model}}
      {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

I wanted to do that when person clicks name it will be redirected to /profile/1 so i wrote:

```
{{#each model}}
      {{#linkTo profile}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

When i point my cursor on name it displays link like this:

```
...#/profile/<App.Profile:ember320:2>
```

And not:

```
...#/profile/2
```

What i do wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model doesn't have a matching field with the slug in your resource map (:id) it won't know how to generate the url.  If this is the case, create a serialize method in your route.

```
App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   serialize: function(model){
    return { id: model.get('whateverTheIdIsInYourModel')};
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'profile' resource has dynamic segments so you have to pass the model while transitioning via linkTo. So something like

```
{{#each model}}
  {{#linkTo profile this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

should work...

Reference to [linkTo](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)

Comment: I've added "this" but it still works the same wrong way. Any other ideas?

Comment: You have to return the id in your serialize hook of the profile route. Can you provide a fiddle to debug ??

Comment: I dont have any serialize hook. All i have is above